# tomcat 7 ( Linux) active directory JNLDIRealm integration

Tags: linux, active-directory, tomcat7, jndi

I'm trying to integrate Tomcat 7 (installed on Linux server) with Active Directory,following documentation

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-auth-howto.html

I have modified server.xml

```
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"
    connectionURL="ldap://dc.domain.local:389"
    connectionName="tc01@domain.local"
    connectionPassword="password"
    userBase="CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=Local"
    userSearch="(&amp;(samAccountName={0})(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))"
    userSubtree="false"
    roleBase="CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=Local"
     roleName="cn"
    roleNested="true"
    roleSearch="(member={0})"
    roleSubtree="false" />
```

I have modified also web.xml of my web application

```
        <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
       <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
       <http-method>GET</http-method>
       <http-method>POST</http-method>
       <http-method>PUT</http-method>
       </web-resource-collection>
       <auth-constraint>
       <role-name>group</role-name>
      </auth-constraint>
       </security-constraint>
         <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>Tomcat Manager Application</realm-name>
        </login-config>
         <security-role>
        <role-name>Everyone</role-name>
         </security-role>
```

When I try to use getRemoteUser() I found user name but not domain name.

```
<%
 response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0);
 %>
<!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title>TEST AD!</title>
 </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
            Your web browser must have JavaScript enabled in order for this
            application to display correctly.</div>
    </noscript>
    <div id="wa_details">
    <div id="wa_user"><%= ((request.getRemoteUser()!=null)?request.getRemoteUser():"") %></div>
   </div>
    <div id="loader"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I cannot understand where is the problem

Regards

Oro